# How can I solve "XML error parsing SOAP payload on line 1: Invalid document end" in PHP Nusoap

Tags: php, xml, soap, nusoap

I am just new to PHP Nusoap and I tried to run my program and I am getting this kind of error when I `print_r($client)`. Here is the error :

> Error: XML error parsing SOAP payload on line 1: Invalid document end

I find some related topics, articles and questions in google they are unanswered and if there are answered it doesn't help or solve my problem
I also print my request and reponse details here it is :

```
**Request**

POST /Nusoap/webservice_server.php HTTP/1.0
Host: sampleserver:8544
User-Agent: NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123)
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1
SOAPAction: "urn:Insertwsdl#InsertData"
Content-Length: 616

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="urn:Insert"><SOAP-ENV:Body><tns:InsertData xmlns:tns="urn:Insert"><data/><data1/><data2/><data3/><data4/></tns:InsertData></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Response

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 26 Nov 2015 06:17:25 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) PHP/5.2.11
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.44
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
X-SOAP-Server: NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123)
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=rftjeluijhnej49rvpu94rs6f0; path=/
Content-Length: 411
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1

Data : Filename of of data
Data1 : Sender of the data
Data2 : Receiver of the data
Data : Filename1 of the data
Data1 : Sender1 of the data
Data2 : Receiver1 of the data
Da
```

for my code :

**webservice_server.php**

```
<?php 
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');

$server = new soap_server();

$server->configureWSDL('Database Data Insertion', 'urn:Insert');
//$server->soap_defencoding = 'utf-8';
$server->register('InsertData',
    array(
        'data' => 'xsd:data',       
        'data1' => 'xsd:data1',
        'data2'  => 'xsd:data2',
        'data3'  => 'xsd:data3',
        'data4' => 'xsd:data4',
    ),
    array(
        'return' => 'xsd:string'        
    ),
    'urn:Insert',
    'urn:Insertwsdl#InsertData',
    'rpc',
    'literal',
    'Retrieve data from  the database'
    );

    function InsertData($data, $data1, $data2, $data3, $data4){

        $db_host = '127.0.0.1';
        $db_username = 'sample';
        $db_password = '' ;
        $db_name = 'sample';

        $conn = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);

        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            trigger_error('Database connection failed: ', $conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
        }

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM sample_transaction ";

        $query = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<br /> Data : " .$row['data'];
                echo "<br /> Data1 : " .$row['data1'];
                echo "<br /> Data2 : "  .$row['data2'];
            }

        } else {
            echo "0 Results";
        }
    }

    $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '' ;
    $server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
?>
```

**webservice_client.php**

```
<?php
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);


$data = $data['data'];
$data1 = $data['data1'];
$data2 = $data['data2'];
$data3= $data['data3'];
$data4 = $data['data4'];
$client = new nusoap_client('http://sampleserver:8544/Nusoap/webservice_server.php?wsdl', true);

$datas = array(
     'data' => $data,
    'data1' => $data1,
    'data2'=> $data2,
    'data3' => $data3,
    'data4' => $data4,  
    );

$result= $client->call('InsertData', $datas);

print_r($result);

echo "<br /><pre>" .$client. "</pre>";
echo "<h2>Request</h2>";
echo "<pre>" .htmlspecialchars($client->request, ENT_QUOTES). "</pre>";
echo "<h2>Response</h2>";
echo "<pre>" .htmlspecialchars($client->response, ENT_QUOTES). "</pre>";
?>
```

I just comment out the `$server->soap_defencoding` because the response will have a content-type like `text/xml charset=utf-8` if not comment out. Is it also a problem if I don't have the same content-type, the charset I mean? Base on the codes I posted above how can I solve this issue because I been looking for solution for this in 2 days. Can someone point out where did I go wrong and how can I solve this? By the way, the code will just select from the database, it retrieves only few data from the database and got that error.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Please keep

```
$server->soap_defencoding = 'utf-8';
```

add

```
$client->soap_defencoding = 'utf-8'; 
$client->encode_utf8 = false;
$client->decode_utf8 = false;
```

if error continues, please add

```
$server->encode_utf8 = false;
$server->decode_utf8 = false;
```

to the server file

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error while posting an xml over https. It was Okay while passing it over http. After days of googling and trying to change some things on my php.ini, I messed up the whole file and so I opted to re-install php5 and it worked.

I used the below command to re-install php

apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I tried to solve it for one day. Unfortunately, I had no solution. After trace my php codes, I saw `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in my config.php file. If you just remove that line or change it to `ini_set('display_errors', 0);` , it will work like a charms.

I hope that will help others to overcome that problem in their SOAP (nusoap) project library or files.

Have a great day.